# React router 4 beta 2 with ReactCSSTransitionGroup

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

I prefer `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` for `react-motion`. The below code causes the component to fade in (appear) on route change, BUT the issue is - the leaving component does not fade out, it leaves instantly.

```js
<Switch>
    <FadeRoute exact path="/" component={PageLanding}/>
    <FadeRoute path="/login" component={PageLogin}/>
    <FadeRoute path="/signup" component={PageSignup}/>
    <FadeRoute component={Page404}/>
</Switch>

function FadeRoute({component:Component, ...rest}) {
    return (
        <Route {...rest} children={({location,match}) => (
                <ReactCSSTransitionGroup {...{key:Date.now(), transitionName:'fade', transitionAppear:true, transitionEnter:true, transitionLeave:true, transitionAppearTimeout:300, transitionEnterTimeout:300, transitionLeaveTimeout:300})}>
                    <Component/>
                </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        )} />
    );
}
```

```css
<style>
.fade-enter, .fade-appear { opacity:0; }
.fade-enter.fade-enter-active,
.fade-appear.fade-appear-active { opacity:1; transition: opacity 300ms; }
.fade-leave { opacity:1; }
.fade-leave.fade-leave-active { opacity:0; transition: opacity 300ms; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The way that a `<Switch>` works is that it only renders the first `<Route>` whose path is matched by the current location. This means that when you navigate, the existing `<FadeRoute>` is immediately unmounted when you navigate. Its child `<CSSTransitionGroup>` is also unmounted, so it has no opportunity to run the leave transition for its children.

What you want to do is to wrap your `<Switch>` in a `<CSSTransitionGroup>`. The `<Switch>` is the component that will be transitioned, so it should have a `key`. You should also pass it the `location` object so that when a `<Switch>` is leaving, it animates using the old `location` instead of the current one.

```
<CSSTransitionGroup
  transitionName='fade'
  transitionEnterTimeout={500}
  transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
>
  <Switch key={location.pathname} location={location}>
    <Route path="/red" render={Red} />
    <Route path="/green" render={Green} />
    <Route path="/blue" render={Blue} />
  </Switch>
</CSSTransitionGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Paul! This way you recommend in solution is the intuitive way when using `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`! I'll watch out for that bug and try the solutions from there! :)

Comment: Hi Paul, just to verify what the issue is. I implemented this and the fading in and out is working perfectly. The issue I'm having is that the fading out component, is updated to the component based on the new route. So its basically fading out then in the same component. This is what that github issue is about?

Comment: Yes, that is the issue.

Comment: Paul, you rock. Everything's so confusing with react router lately, I just had implemented a site with alpha.6 version and 3 weeks later i come back to see it's on beta.4! Well I also followed your thread on github, let's see how long until they fix this in! Thanks for sharing your experiences.

Comment: Have you got this working now? I'm also experimenting with the combo CSSTransitionGroup and Switch.

Comment: This works now. You can pass a `location` object to the `<Switch>` so that its children render using the correct location.

Comment: @per_jansson yep this has already landed in `beta.7` and is definitely in the release of v4. Definitely read that github issue topic - https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4351 - especially the comments towards the end. It is really confusing at first because there are two `location` objects. There is `props.location` and `props.history.location`. Make sure to pass in `props.location` to the switch and it fixes things up.

Comment: Would you mind updating this answer to include the `location={location}` on the `Switch` component?